# Symfony connect with algolia problem get Argument #1 ($object) must be of type object, int given

Tags: symfony, algolia, symfony5.4

I have a question: I need to get communication with algolia, but i cannot get that work, since of leak of documentation. I have symfony 5.4 but algora docs provide only for version 4, second when I trying to get some of my entities indexed i get stuck at the point when i have to provide `entityManager` which suppose to implement `ObjectManager`, but that one it is not wired in the service. And how many people suggest we should not use this directly and use `EntityManagerInteface` instead. So how i have to index my Entity?

What i did:

```
composer require algolia/search-bundle
```

Added credentials:

```
ALGOLIA_APP_ID="U1RFIHY01W"
ALGOLIA_API_KEY="YourAPIKey"
```

Trying to index in the controller for testing:

```
public function searchPosts(Post $post, ManagerRegistry $em): JsonResponse
    {
        $posts = $this->postRepository->searchPosts('82819');
        $postsArray = [];

        /**@var Post $post */
        foreach ($posts as $post){
            $postsArray = $post->normalize();
        }

        $this->searchService->index($em->getManager(), $postsArray);


        return new JsonResponse($this->searchService->getConfiguration());
    }
```

Right now since i use `ManagerRegestry` i get an error:

```
get_class(): Argument #1 ($object) must be of type object, int given
```

Can you help me work around? Thank you

Comment: 1) you can inject EntityManagerInterface directly, no need to inject ManagerRegistry. 2) you sure searchPosts supports '82819' as argument and not a Post object? 3) where is $lpostsArray coming from?

Comment: @LBA i switched to work with `Elasticsearch` because unavailability to reformat their plugin  to work with Symfony 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Separate the two instructions with :

`$entityManager= $em->getManager();`

and then

`$this->searchService->index($entityManager, $lpostsArray);`